# Call a function from a subview UIViewController Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have ADMINviewController that contains a UITableView and contains a function called **Request** that loads the devices from the server and fill the UITableView, when I select a cell, which is a device name, VehicleInfoViewController as a subview opens to let me change the device name.

So what I want is to call the **Request** function after showing a message that the device name has changed successfully, in order to reload the data from the server and update the UITableView with the new device name.

How to call the **Request** function from the subview?

Comment: your architecture is not clear you have a viewController as a subview? Or you push it? Any way you can use NSNotificationCenter or some kind of a flag which you can check in viewWillAppear or use delegation...

Comment: when i select a cell from the uitableview i call the VehicleInfoViewController like that [self.view addSubview:deviceInfoViewController.view]; so i want to call the Request function that is in the previous viewcontroller

Comment: I think this a strange bit of code - [self.view addSubview:deviceInfoViewController.view]; you should consider about pushing another view controller....

Comment: this is exactly how i am showing the another view controller
   
 deviceInfoViewController = [[DeviceInfoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DeviceInfoViewController" bundle:nil]; 

       [UIView transitionWithView:self.view duration:0.2 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop | UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews |UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent  animations:^{ [self.view addSubview:deviceInfoViewController.view]; }
                    completion:NULL];

Comment: as for me this is weird..view controller usually created to be pushed or presented modally and contains some logic..here you need simply another view I think..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to call Request method which is in ADMINviewController class from VehicleInfoViewController class you should pass a pointer of ADMINviewController instance to VehicleInfoViewController.

Add id property to VehicleInfoViewController class like this:

```
@property(nonatomic,assign)id adminController;
```

Then after you create VehicleInfoViewController instance, pass self pointer to it like this:

```
vehicleInfoViewController = [[VehicleInfoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"vehicleInfoViewController" bundle:nil];
vehicleInfoViewController.adminController = self;
```

When you need to call Request method being inside vehicleInfoViewController do this:

```
[self.adminController performSelector:@selector(Request)];
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!! Thank you so much for a simple and elegant solution!  :)

Answer (score 2):

The approach above (by Rafael) can also be used by a subView to call a method located in that subView's viewController. Just make sure to add the necessary methods to avoid compiler warnings, e.g., use

```
@synthesize adminController
```

in the implementation of the VehicleInfoViewController class for the above example. This  can also be called from within any object that has a VehicleInfoViewController instance. For example, assuming parentObject contains a vehicleInfoViewController member variable, calling Request within the parentObject would look like:

```
[parentObject.adminController performSelector:@selector(Request)];
```